# How can I access a program from server through Firefox browser?

Tags: firefox

I want to access a program on server across my network. The program should be accessible through Firebox on a client machine but I don't seem to be able to point to the server correctly. Any help appreciated.

The program is Oscaremr12

Comment: Is the application configured to have external access on the LAN (that is to say, can the network 'see' the server and the application on it)?  Make sure you use the right host name and address and port.

Answer (score 0):

First you should know the port of the software.
Then type in the address bar of firefox:

```
<Address of the host>:<port number>
```

To find the software port it is easy to use "Nmap":
first install Nmap and then type in terminal:

```
nmap <host name or Ip Address>
```

Then you can see the ports of softwares on the host.

Probably, It is on the port 8080, and you should type in the address bar:

```
http://<Domain name or Ip address>:8080/oscar or https://<Domain name or Ip address>:8443/oscar
```

Or if it is on your own machine, type localhost for Domain name.
Complete information is [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31541872/Step-by-Step-Install-Guide-OSCAR-McMaster-eHealth-CMS-on-Ubuntu-10-04-LTS-v1-5).